# Lost ubuntu option from boot

Tags: 12.10, boot, bootloader

I was using **ubuntu 12.10** until i lost all options from boot in somehow, but I've restored my (2) windows 7 options **successfully** using windows 7 format DVD and solved the problem using command prompt and some commands, **but i don't know how to get the ubuntu option back**, u know it is installed on my computer but **i can't use it, i can't open it**

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you recovered Windows, you used the Windows bootloader which doesn't recognise linux. therefore you need to reinstall grub.

You will need an liveDVD or liveUSB Ubuntu or even better the [Ubuntu-Secure-Remix](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UbuntuSecureRemix) disk.

If you opt for a standard Ubuntu live medium, you have to install Boot-Repair.

1. In Ubuntu live, open a terminal and run: `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:yannubuntu/boot-repair` followed by `sudo apt-get update`
2. Install Boot-repair with `sudo apt-get install -y boot-repair`
3. Run Boot repair and follow instructions.

Answer (score -1):

You will need to install the ubuntu version again as you lost **ALL** of the options in the boot menu. But all your files on the previous version of 12.10 will be lost.

And was you messing around with the computer (Eg. Using Terminal/Command Prompt) before you rebooted to see no boot options?

Comment: in fact who was missing around is windows 8 installer
which didn't complete (because of compatibility issues), and caused me some fatal errors

Comment: He doesn't need to reinstall, nor will his files be lost if he does.